# collision in wix extension: NetFxExtension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wix, wix3.10

I am trying to create a bootstrapper project in Visual Studio 2015 using Wix.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="..." Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="mtel-eula-free.rtf"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixBootstrapperApplication:WixNetFxExtension" />
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload
        Name="BootstrapperCore.config"
        SourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload
        SourceFile="$(var.TargetPath)"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="MTESetup" SourceFile="$(var.MTESetup.TargetPath)"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

The project name for the bootstrapper is MTEBootstrapper and the project name for the wix project for the MSI is MTESetup. For MTEBootstrapper, I added a reference to WixNetFxExtension.dll from Wix 3.10; In the properties of MTEBootstrapper, I added `-ext WixNetFxExtension.dll`. Now I am getting this error when I try to build MTEBootstrapper:

```
Error       The extension 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.NetFxExtension' contains a defintion for table 'NetFxNativeImage' that collides with a previously loaded table definition.  Please remove one of the conflicting extensions or rename one of the tables to avoid the collision.   MTEBootstrapper light.exe   0
```

I have no idea what is causing this. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this error surfaces when I have both the reference to WixNetFxExtension added to MTEBootstrapper and the -ext option for the linker. I removed the -ext option for the linker and collision error disappeared.

(Separately I am getting an unresolved symbol WixNetFxExtension, which I will file a separate question for.)