# How to start service in installer with conditions included

Tags: windows, service, wix, windows-installer

I use WIX installer  to install service as well as start it during install,however in some situations where required prerequisites like VC redistributable is not completely installed I want to avoid starting service
How can it be achieved
Currently I am using ServiceInstall and ServiceControl to install and start service

```
<ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                 Start="install"
                 Stop="both"
                 Remove="uninstall" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of MSI standard actions which uses ServiceInstall and ServiceControl table. You need to add conditions in InstallExecuteSequence table for the following standard custom actions:

StopServices

DeleteServices

InstallServices

MsiConfigureServices

StartServices

Comment: Any idea on how to resolve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404644/collision-in-wix-extension-netfxextension ,I am hitting similar issue